# Android studio kotlin, how to refresh app every second

Tags: android, kotlin

Today I am trying to refresh Date() in jetpack compose. I want it refresh the time and date secondly to push my countermeter, for e.x. alike https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07ZdBCyh7sc

```
                        var dateNow = remember { MutableStateFlow<Date>(Date())}

                        var date = dateNow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                        var update: boolean = false
                        if (date.value.seconds = Date().seconds) {
                            //delay(1000L)
                            dateNow = Date()
                            Text(text = "${date.value}")
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`LaunchedEffect` is an effect handler that should work for you